# combinations of list repeated N times python

Tags: python

I have a list `l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and would like to generate all possible combinations assuming the elements of `l` are repeated `N` times.

Example:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] with N = 2 would yield

`[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5]`

`[2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5]`

`[3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5]`

`[4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4], [4, 5]`

`[5, 1], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5]`

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `itertools.product`:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(map(list, product([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], repeat=2)))
[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4], [4, 5], [5, 1], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5]]
```

Comment: And replace `repeat=2` with `repeat=N`, where N is however many repetitions you want.